# How to give root privileges to user

Tags: permissions

I've tried everything but nothing seem to work. I've also looked through examples already posted. Recently, I wiped my Mac and had to start over. Prior to that I saved some files so I wouldn't have to completely start over and one was an Ubuntu VM (22.04 lts. For whatever reason, I can't edit config files because I don't have permission, they're locked. Looks as though the root user has permission but when I chance to root, it still doesn't work.

```
larryt@ubuntu01:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu01: Name or service not known
[sudo] password for larryt: 
root@ubuntu01:/home/larryt# ls -l /usr/local/share/doc/glances.conf
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/share/doc/glances.conf': No such file or directory
root@ubuntu01:/home/larryt# ls -l /usr/local/share/doc/glances
total 192
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1706 Sep 27 17:35 AUTHORS
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6086 Sep 27 17:35 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42098 Sep 27 17:35 COPYING
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20994 Sep 28 12:47 glances.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21033 Sep 27 21:44 glances.conf.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71000 Sep 27 17:35 NEWS.rst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 16100 Sep 27 17:35 README.rst
```

I am the only user there I need to be able to edit anything.
Thanks

Comment: You path is wrong.  Try /usr/local/share/doc/glances/glances.conf

Answer (score 2):

> ls -l /usr/local/share/doc/glances.conf

is missing a `glances/`.

If you want to edit do

```
sudo vi /usr/local/share/doc/glances/glances.conf
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it.